# Printing confidence values with PocketSphinx

Tags: c, speech-recognition, confidence-interval, pocketsphinx

I have the following code in a program of mine:

```
cmd_ln_t *config = cmd_ln_init(NULL, ps_args(), TRUE,
                                   "-hmm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us",
                                   "-lm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us.lm.bin",
                                   "-dict", MODELDIR "/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict",
                                   NULL);
ps_decoder_t *ps = ps_init(config);
// ...
const char *text = recognizeFromFile(ps, fileName);
// ...
fprintf(stdout, "Recognized text: %s\n", text);
fprintf(stdout, "Confidence: %g%%\n", logmath_exp(ps_get_logmath(ps), ps_get_prob(ps)) * 100);
```

But every time I get a confidence output, it doesn't exactly seem like the value I'm looking for is being printed correctly.

For example, here is a case of me saying "test" and the output generated:

> ```
> Recognized text: toes
> Confidence: 8.17663%
> ...
> Recognized text: test
> Confidence: 0.195157%
> ```

As you can see from the first time I say it, the program guesses what I say incorrectly but still has a higher confidence value than when it actually guesses it correctly.

From what I've garnered from the internet, I thought I've been calculating the confidence correctly.  Is that incorrect?  How can I fix it to make the output be more accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I've garnered from the internet, I thought I've been calculating the confidence correctly. Is that incorrect?

Your code is correct

> How can I fix it to make the output be more accurate?

There are many issues leading to worse accuracy, most are not related to the code, one of them is incorrect input format. Another is bad recognition of the first sample due to the slow volume estimation. Following samples are usually recognized correctly. To get help on this you need to provide full data to reproduce your problem as in [FAQ](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qwhy_my_accuracy_is_poor).

Comment: But would that worsened accuracy be leading to why the confidence values seemed to be switched though?

Comment: Bad accuracy means confidence could have arbitrary value. So you should not rely on the first recognition at all.

Comment: But wouldn't that be the best guess that PocketSphinx has?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite get your question. When audio is not properly set, for example, in the first recognition attempt, the result is bad and the confidence is bad as well. This is because audio detectors do not work at all. You should not think confidence would have any meaning.

Comment: The thing is that algorithm computes confidence by comparing decoding variants. If all variants are wrong, confidence is wrong. It does not have idea about "something went totally wrong". Overall, our confidence value is far from being perfect, you should not rely much on it.

Comment: Is there any point in printing it out for the user then? I was expecting a value somewhat similar to the confidence value returned from the Google Speech Recognition API but I don't think I can get anything like that now based on what you're saying.

Comment: Google should have same trouble as well, this is how algorithm works. If you try to recognize speech with music on background, you'll see high confidences and bad results.